# SMTP send not working from 4G despite working from wifi

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp, gmail, smtplib

I'm working on a school project with waveshare 4g hat and sim card attached to a raspberry pi 4. It remotely takes images and emails them to a specified user using an account my team setup. When I'm connected to wifi it emails the image fine, however when I disconnect the wifi and use the sim card it doesn't. I'm using a bash script provided by waveshare that setups up a network connection (to att) for http, and I'm able to surf the web and access websites using 4g, however when I try to send the image in python using the smtplib it connects to the email account and logs in fine but then hangs without sending the image at:

```
 s.send_message(m)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 967, in send_message
    rcpt_options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 882, in sendmail
   (code, resp) = self.data(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 568, in data
    self.send(q)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 354, in send
    self.sock.sendall(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1015, in sendall
    v = self.send(byte_view[count:])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 984, in send
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
```

Not having a strong understanding of these protocols I'm assuming it has something to do with the fact that http and smtp are different protocols and it requires some kind of secure connection it looks like? what does connecting to a network via my ISP do that my 4g service does not? Is there a simple fix? I've read elsewhere to make sure that the gmail account that I'm connecting to to send the image has "allow less secure apps" which I have done. Any direction would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
import smtplib
import ssl
import re

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

USERNAME = <removed>
PASSWORD = <removed>

ADDRESS = "<removed>@gmail.com"
 
def send_mail(picture_path, text_string):
print("sending email")
to_address = get_email(text_string)
if to_address == FAIL:
    return
picture = get_picture(picture_path)

m = MIMEMultipart()
m["To"] = to_address
m["From"] = USERNAME
m["Subject"] = "Wildlife Remote"
m.attach(MIMEImage(picture))
print("photo attached")

s = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=587)
s.ehlo()
s.starttls()

s.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
print("email successfully logged in")
s.send_message(m)
s.quit()
print("email sent")
```

and in case its helpful the shell script for setting up the 4g hat that I'm using:

```bash
sudo qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --dms-set-operating-mode='online'

sudo qmicli --d /dev/cdc-wdm0 -w

sudo ip link set wwan0 down

echo 'Y' | sudo tee /sys/class/net/wwan0/qmi/raw_ip

sudo ip link set wwan0 up

sudo qmicli -p -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --device-open-net='net-raw-ip|net-no-qos-header' --wds- 
start-network="apn='phone',ip-type=4" --client-no-release-cid

sudo qmi-network /dev/cdc-wdm0 start

sudo udhcpc -i wwan0
```

Comment: Different providers may have different policies regarding whether they permit direct smtp access to outgoing mail servers other than their own ones; some may block such connections to force you to use their own mailserver, as part of anti-spam measures.

Comment: ah ok that's super helpful thank you! So would that be a question for ATT then?

Comment: It would be worth asking. Also see if you can find out the name (and port number) to use for their smtp server, and then see if it works if you use that in place of the gmail one when sending mail from their network.

Comment: The error traceback seems to be truncated, can you provide the complete traceback please?